# CreatedAtAction and Routing in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api-routing, asp.net-core-1.0

There is an api, implemented by means of Asp.Net Core. There are two controllers `GoodsController` and `StoreController`. After assigning a good to a store, it is necessary to redirect user to the new version of the good.

There are two problems with this workflow:

1. `CreatedAtAction("Get", "goods", new { id = goodModel.Id }, goodModel)` gives us .../api/goods?id=123, what I want is .../api/goods/123.
2. I wasn't able to get .../api/goods/123 route from `CreatedAtAction(...)`, so I decided to create one more action that takes id from query, but asp.net isn't able to tell method `GetAll()` from `GetFromQuery([FromQuery] int id)`.

Is there a way to solve at least one of these problems?
The code is given below.

```
[Route("api/[controller]", Name = "GoodsController")]
public class GoodsController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<GoodModel> GetAll()
    {
        //Returns goods
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get0FromQuery([FromQuery] int id)
    {
        //Returns good by id
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}", Name = "GetGood")]
    public GoodModel Get([FromRoute]int id)
    {
        //Returns good by id
    }
}

[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class StoreController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("goods")]
    public IActionResult Post([FromBody] AssignGoodToStoreCommand command)
    {
        //Assign good to store, get goodModel
        return CreatedAtAction("Get", "goods", new { id = goodModel.Id }, goodModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: " I wasnt able to get .../api/goods/123 route"  How were you expecting  ?. Your code looks fine. It should respond with `/api/goods/123`. Are you saying it is not.

Comment: He wants `api/goods/123` but gets `api/goods?id=123`

Comment: No! with the code he posted in the question, It should return `api/goods/123` because he has a Route definition with that pattern defined for his `Ge`t method of GoodsController. I just copied and pasted this code and worked fine for me ( i got `api/goods/123`).

Comment: I think you can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38389733/3315560)