# ASP.Net Core CreatedAtAction in HttpPost action returns 201 but entire request ends with 500

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, iis-7.5, iis-express

I'm following[1] for setting up my first .NET Core WebAPI (moving from "old" WebAPI). When I do HttpPost action, as in tutorial:

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Create([FromBody] TodoItem item)
{
    if (item == null)
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }
    TodoItems.Add(item);
    return CreatedAtAction("GetTodo", new { id = item.Key }, item);
}
```

I get a HttpError 500 after exiting my Controller. `CreatedAtAction` returns proper object with Status Code 201 as I would expect, and after my method exits the Server somehow turns it into 500. I don't seem to be able to step into the rest of the pipeline. Trace gives me following error:

```
81.  -GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY 
82.  -NOTIFY_MODULE_COMPLETION 
83.  -MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS [Warning] 171ms

      ModuleName          AspNetCoreModule 
      Notification        EXECUTE_REQUEST_HANDLER 
      HttpStatus          500 
      HttpReason          Internal Server Error 
      HttpSubStatus       0 
      ErrorCode           The operation completed successfully. (0x0) 
      ConfigExceptionInfo
```

Everything (Program.cs, Startup.cs) are set up exactly as in[1]. Behaves exactly the same in IISExpress (VS2015 Update 3) and IIS7.5 (Windows 7). Other return types, 200 (with `new ObjectResult(item)` for GET, 404 for `NotFound()` or 204 `NoContentResult()` for PUT work ok. So it seems like it's a problem with 201 somehow. Any ideas?

[1] https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/first-web-api.html

**update**
Posting additional details per request:

Startup.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using FirstWebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FirstWebApi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();
            services.AddLogging();
            services.AddSingleton<ITodoRepository, TodoRepository>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseStatusCodePages();

            app.UseMvc();   
        }
    }
}
```

TodoController.cs:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using FirstWebApi.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace FirstWebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class TodoController : Controller
    {
        public TodoController(ITodoRepository todoItems)
        {
            TodoItems = todoItems;
        }
        public ITodoRepository TodoItems { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<TodoItem> GetAll()
        {
            return TodoItems.GetAll();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetTodo")]
        public IActionResult GetById(string id)
        {
            var item = TodoItems.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }
            return new ObjectResult(item);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Create([FromBody] TodoItem item)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
            TodoItems.Add(item);
            return CreatedAtAction("GetTodo", new { id = item.Key }, item);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public IActionResult Update(string id, [FromBody] TodoItem item)
        {
            if (item == null || item.Key != id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var todo = TodoItems.Find(id);
            if (todo == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            TodoItems.Update(item);
            return new NoContentResult();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(string id)
        {
            TodoItems.Remove(id);
        }
    }
}
```

**update 2**

turns out, `CreateAtAction` with 201 tries to redirect to unhandled route:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.CreatedAtActionResult.OnFormatting(ActionContext context)
```

Still not sure why tho, as the method `GetById` should be mapped to `GetTodo` per Controller settings.

Comment: Maybe post your `Startup.cs` so we can see if you are using some odd middleware or so? Also your GetTodo method would be useful

Comment: @Tseng Thanks. Didn't include it in the original post, because all I had in `Startup.cs` was scaffolding from `New > Project > ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) > Web Api` + `UseDeveloperExceptionPages`. The only thing I have different than what you would have following tutorial step-by-step is that `UseDeveloperExceptionPages` I added after I hit the problem in hope I will get more info. I didn't. `Create` method exits correctly with an object containing new item and 201 passed through from `CreateAtAction`. It's not throwing anything. The item is added to repository as expected too.

Comment: Btw. Not sure if that changes anything, but I'm also using Fiddler4 to craft the POST request, with proper headers - which again, I don't think matters a lot as the controller exits properly and does what it should, ie. it adds an item to the repository.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, after a bit of debugging I found what caused it. It turned out that `this.Url.Action("Get", "GetTodo", new { id=item.Key })` would return `null` and the 500 came from the fact that IIS could not match route attached to 201.

As it turns out, You either need to setup:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action}");
});
```

or use `CreateAtRoute`.

Answer (score -2):

On a successfull POST request I use:

```
return StatusCode(201, oCreatedObject);
```

Comment: IIRC the way you did it there does not populate the location header with the resource location. which is not as RESTful as it can be.